# Create array with query MongoDb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have this Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200a"),  
    "name" : "foo"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200e"),
    "name" : "bar"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200f"),    
    "name" : "baz"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200b"),
    "name" : "biz"
}
```

and I want an array ids

I did this

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {_id: 1})
```

and return

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200a")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200e")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200f")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200b")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff000010200c")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55555555ffffff0000103111")
}
```

Can I have an array?
    id['55555555ffffff0000103111','55555555ffffff0000103111','555555555ffffff0000103111','55555555ffffff0000103111']

Comment: I have edited my answer with another option.  Check if that's more suited to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Option 1:** If an array of subdocuments is acceptable, you can just append [.toArray()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) to the find query.

```js
> db.test.find({}, {_id:1}).toArray()
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53270b12d111b9bf595f4270")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53270b14d111b9bf595f4271")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("53270b16d111b9bf595f4272")
        }
]
```

**Option 2:** Another option is to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).

```js
> db.test.aggregate([{$group:{_id:null, ids:{$push:"$_id"}}}, {$project:{_id:0, ids:1}}])
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "ids" : [
                                ObjectId("53270b12d111b9bf595f4270"),
                                ObjectId("53270b14d111b9bf595f4271"),
                                ObjectId("53270b16d111b9bf595f4272")
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Option 3:  Or you can use [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) in the shell like this:

```
> var myIds = new Array()
> db.test.find({},{_id:1}).forEach(function(myDoc){myIds.push(myDoc._id.str)})
> myIds
[
        "53270b12d111b9bf595f4270",
        "53270b14d111b9bf595f4271",
        "53270b16d111b9bf595f4272"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct to turn a single column into an array:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('_id', function(err, list){
 //list is an array of ObjectId
});
```